# Batch Data import to Geonetwork

Tags: geonetwork

I'm in the process of attempting the set up of a GeoNetwork instance and have been given an xls with metadata for 1200+ maps.

Has anyone seen docs for a good workflow for batch import? Maybe xls templates which match the GeoNetwork ISO19139 templates? Or a postgres DB template I could copy them into which I could then connect to GeoNetwork?

I tried to export the GeoNetwork ISO19139 templates as xml and bring them into excel but the formatting gets lost and their not usable.

Ideas?

Comment: why do you need to convert the XML to Excel? You can import ISO 19139 XML records using the API (https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/api/the-geonetwork-api.html), for example POST to /geonetwork/srv/api/0.1/records (check docs at https://vanilla.geocat.net/geonetwork/doc/api/#/records/insertFile)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I have an excel spreadsheet with 1200+ maps records entered, with columns for title, abstract, publication date etc. I want to get these into XML so I can import them but I'm not clear on the best workflow to do this.

Comment: Then you would need to generate XML files from that Excel document and import those new files into GN.
For the transformation you could program it yourself or use some ETL tool like Talend (https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio/) to read the Excel, apply the transformation and maybe push the result to GeoNetwork.

Comment: @juanluisrp ok, will give that a go, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a script to take CSV and write 19139 XML which will solve the issue - https://github.com/AstunTechnology/gemini_csv_import

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeoFlow which is what you want: https://github.com/eblondel/geoflow

Comment: Doesn't seem like it can match all ISO 19139 metadata fields yet, looking at https://github.com/eblondel/geoflow/blob/master/doc/Summary_metadata.csv